# How to show that there exists $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that $f'(\xi)=\frac{f(\xi)-f(a)}{\xi-a}$

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives, rolles-theorem, mean-value-theorem

Given that $f(x)$ is differentiable on the closed interval $[a,b]$ and $f'(a)=f'(b)$.How can I prove that there exists $\xi \in (a,b)$ such that$$f'(\xi)=\frac{f(\xi)-f(a)}{\xi-a}$$
I have tried to let
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}&a<x\leq b \\
f'(a)&x=a \\
\end{cases}
$$
And it's easy know that when $a<x < b$,$$F'(x)=\frac{f'(x)(x-a)-[f(x)-f(a)]}{(x-a)^2}$$
If $F(a)=F(b)$,we can easily prove the statement with Rolle's theorem.But I don't think it's possible to prove $F(a)=F(b)$ here.
So I am totally at a loss what to do now.

Comment: This is a well-known [theorem](https://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m555/current/hw/MVT-Flett.pdf) by Flett.